# be going back to work for the first time since

Tags: present-perfect, since

Mom said,

> I'm going back to work at the hospital tonight for the first time *since* Charles was born.

Is this a correct sentence? I heard of it on a TV program. I think "since" is used with present perfect tense. But here, it's not the present perfect. So does it work? If it does, can I apply the princal to other sentences with the same tense, the future tense?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is correct. It means that the speaker has not worked at the hospital after Charles was born, but will do so tonight.

The word *since* here means *after a past time*:

[American Heritage Dictionary *since*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=since)
conjunction 1. During the period subsequent to the time when:
*He hasn't been home since he graduated.*

The phrase *Charles was born* means the time when Charles was born, and *since Charles was born* means *beginning at that time, and continuing up to now*.

Comment: What makes the sentence in question correct is the phrase  "for the first time" , right? Without it, does the sentence still make sense?

Comment: That's right. She could have said "I have been on maternity leave since Charles was born", but with the future tense you need _for the first time_ or its equivalent.